# Pass a value in .sh file at the time of execution

Tags: shell-script

Hi i have a script script.sh which asks to pass a value at the time of execution such as 1 for backup 2 for copy 3 for print. In which i have to pass a value through command line.
I just want to pass those values automatically at the time of execution of the shell file. Please provide a solution.

Comment: What have you tried? Scripts accepting parameters or options on the command line are completely standard and it's easy to find tons of examples of that. "Please provide a solution.", in addition to being rude, is not how this site works.

Comment: Incidentally, I would not recommend something like "1 for backup 2 for copy" etc... Why not "backup for backup, copy for copy", etc... Easier to remember, yes?

Comment: The question is not clear. You can't pass a command line argument at any other time *than* at the time of execution. Please reformulate and give examples.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I deduce you are expecting your script to behave like a complex daemon, which wold invoke itself programmatically.

I think you should write another script to manage the level of automation you require. Said script wold invoke the one you have, with the logic you require

Comment: do u plz suggest. the syntax under the script

Comment: No. It is not clear what you want to do. Be much more specific

Answer (score -3):

In bash, you can do:

```
alias script.sh='script.sh 1'
```

To always run `script.sh 1` when `script.sh` is typed.

Comment: but if I want to pass 2 and 3 automatically after a certain period?

Comment: aliases which have the same name as their underlying commands tend to confuse everyone. `it works when I try it at the command line but doesn't work in a script`.

Comment: @icarus Well, computers are confusing generally.